# Switch Between Graphic And Text Mode in Turbo C

Tags: c, graphics

Guys i am writing a simple graphic program to create a **polygon of n sides** by taking input from the user.After obtaining co-ordinates of vertices i would ask user to enter the vertex pairs between which he wants an edge.

To make this **more interactive** i thought i would gradually start drawing the polygon in graphic mode simulatneously i.e i would gradually add the edges and would display it to the user .Now i would again switch to the text mode to obtain further set of vertices between which he wants to insert edges.But what i found that as i switch between graphics and text mode everything which **i draw in graphics mode is erased .**

Guys is **there any way or any function in turbo C compiler** so that i could switch between text and graphic mode and at the same time restoring the contents of graphic mode.**Should i use different compiler??**

Comment: wow... Borland's BGI? It's been a looooong time...

Comment: @Pablo yeah, I learned to code in Turbo C... about 15 years ago! Pretty great IDE before ubiquitous internet. The help was great :)

Comment: How about a different language too?!!

Comment: @Rolf Rander: given that he's stated that is using Turbo C, I guess it's DOS (probably running under windows nowadays).

Comment: @rolf Rander i am using win xp .@Byron Today also when it comes to learning graphics programming TURBO C is preffered.Do you know some other compiler in which i can do graphic programming.

Comment: I was about to suggest moving to MinGW and qt or something similar, but that would not be a good place to start learning C...  If you know C and want to get in to graphics, it might work, though.  (I haven't tried this combination myself, and google told me there is no easy tutorial for it...)

Comment: @Algorithmist- Any compiler should let you program a graphical application, it's all in the libraries you use.  The syntax probably won't be the same as the graphics libraries built into the Turbo C compiler, but there are a wide variety of graphics libraries available (OpenGL, DirectX, etc).

Comment: +1 for Turbo C. Takes me back. Unfortunately, not far enough back to help you with your question, but good luck anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching between modes makes the video adapter lose all retained graphics.  A workaround for this is to use a 'canvas', an in-memory bitmap that stores the pixels.  You'd make modifications to this bitmap and blit it to the video adapter to make it visible.  Not supported by this ancient graphics library you use.  Review the CreateCompatibleDC() winapi function in you plan to get ahead.

This is hardly a problem.  Simply re-render the graphics when you switch back to graphics mode.  You do have to store a 'model' of the polygon so you can render it.  Just store the vertex points.

Answer (score 1):

You could use restorecrtmode(),setmode() and getmode() functions available in TURBO c library.These functions are present in graphics.h header file.

Answer (score 0):

You may stay in graphics mode to get user input, but you will need to create a input function that works in graphic mode, reading char by char (getch()), composing your input and updating the graphic screen with the characters typed. If your graphic card have more then one page, you can use "setactivepage" and "setvisualpage" to create separated pages for the data entry and graphic.